# ics format for events bound to weeks, not particular days or times

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I would like to export some events from my webapp into .ics format so that I can load them on Google Calendar.

I am aware that for "standard" day&time events, the DTSTART format would be something like:

```
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
```

The fact is that my events are bound to weeks (e.g.: "list your wants" on week 13), not days. What should I use instead on the line quoted above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a date-only time, such as:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:19970714
```

End then end the event 1 week later, with either

```
DTEND:19970721
```

Or

```
DURATION:P7D
```